# Xtext : prevent for matching keywords from another rule

Tags: xtext

I'm looking for a way to prevent KEYWORDS matching at a place where those KEYWORDS are not expected.

Take a look at the following grammar. Both '**APPLY**' and '**OUTPUT**' are keywords.
'**OUTPUT**' has an argument that contains any characters.

Everything works fine but if this argument contains the word **APPLY**, an error is raised (extraneous input APPLY expecting RULE_END).

Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks.

**Sample text**

```
APPLY, 'an id' $
OUTPUT, A text $
OUTPUT, A text with the word APPLY $
```

**DSL**

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    statement+=Statement*;

Statement:
    ApplyStatement | OutputStatement;

OutputStatement:
    'OUTPUT' ',' out+=EXTENDLABEL* end=END;

ApplyStatement:
    'APPLY' ',' id=LABELIDENTIFIER end=END;

terminal fragment LETTER:
    'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T'
    | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm' |
    'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z';

terminal LABELIDENTIFIER:
    "'"->"'";

terminal EXTENDLABEL:
    (LETTER) (LETTER)*;

terminal END:
    '$' !('\n' | '\r')*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few different ways your issue can be handled. First of all, you could escape the keywords appearing, e.g. the Xbase language uses the '^' character as an escape character; if for any reason there is a problem with writing a keyword, you can prefix it with '^', and it would work. Similarly, if you would put your string inside specific symbols, e.g. apostrophes, it would help a lot. Of course, these solutions require to change your language itself, which you may or may not do.

You might also replace your EXTENDLABEL terminal with a datatype rule. This allows greater flexibility with regards to conflict resolution; worst case you could add the language keywords as options. I was suggested this route by a tangentially [related case in the Eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1712138/#msg_1712138).

Comment: First solutions are not acceptable since I can update the language itself. "Worst case solution may work but my language contains hundreds of keywords.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to say I **cannot** update the language!

Comment: I understand the constraint about not changing the language syntax; in this case, the only way that could work is to provide a data type rule for the EXTENDLABEL. As EXTENDLABEL is not allowed to include a ';' character, it should be possible to use that as a terminal character, thus you don't have to change your syntax. Adding the language keywords themselves might be the real last resort.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the EXTENDLABEL data type rule and the terminal ';' as you mentioned. May you detail your suggestion?

Comment: Sry, that was a half-described idea at that point. The problem with your grammar is that keywords cannot be distinguished from some EXTENDLABEL instances. One way to avoid (or at least reduce) the issue is to model them differently (maybe the series of EXTENDLABELs as a single rule finished by a ';' symbol, and then programmatically split them at the separators). I am not sure whether this idea would work or not, but it might worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

an other solution is to change the ID of your token before that your parser used it. Token are provided by the lexer and your parser will take these tokens in input to produce your AST. So the idea is to change the tokens before to pass them to your parser.

To do it you need to declare your own parser:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends IParser> bindIParser() {
    return ModelParser.class;
}
```

Note : your parser will extends the generated parser of your grammar.

Then you need to override the following method to introduce your own TokenSource:

```
override protected XtextTokenStream createTokenStream(TokenSource tokenSource) {
    return new TokenSource(tokenSource, getTokenDefProvider());
}
```

You own token source need to extend 'XtextTokenStream'.

After you need to override the method 'LT' as following :

```
override LT(int k) {
    var Token token = super.LT(k)
    if(token != null && token.text != null) token.tokenOverride(k);
    token
}
```

Then you just need to change the ID :

```
def void tokenOverride(Token token, int index){
    switch (token.text){
        case "APPLY" : {
            overrideType(t_parameter, InternalModelParser.RULE_ID);
        }
    }
 }

def void overrideType(Token token, int i) {
    token.type = i
}
```

Note : don't forget to add your condition before to change the ID of your token, in this example all token 'APPLY' will become an ID.

And of course inside the switch you can use the ID of the token 'APPLY' instead the text of your token.

Comment: My condition is the context and I can find any way to get info about the current context.

Comment: You can get the context by getting the previous or next token. You need to add your own logic.